# Where to see already unlocked combos?

Tags: castle-crashers

Where can I see already unlocked combos in Castle Crashers? I know you can google for combo list, but I'd rather check it in game because i remapped controls.

Comment: I don't think you can, I've never seen that option so far.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excerpt from my personal combo list, it is written platform independent so it should be easier to read when you have remapped controls.

`La` = Light attack button
`Ha` = Heavy attack button
`Jump` = Jump button
`Use` = The button to use an item

`Sprint` = Holding a direction gets you in the sprinting state
`Air` = Perform combo in the air
`Magic` = Hold down magic

`,` = Press the buttons in the sequence they are in
`+` = Press the buttons at the same time
`OR` = Press either button

### Default combo's

```
+----------------+-------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Name           | Level | Combo      | Notes                                                                                         |
+----------------+-------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Jumping strike | 1     | Jump + La  | This should be you main jumping technique because it let's you maintain momentum when landing |
+----------------+-------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Jumping slam   | 1     | Jump + Ha  |                                                                                               |
+----------------+-------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Throw          | 1     | Ha         | You have to stand close to an enemy and holding a direction let's you control the direction   |
+----------------+-------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Stomp          | 1     | Ha         | You have to stand on top of a downed enemy                                                    |
+----------------+-------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### Unlockable combo's by level

```
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Name              | Level | Combo              | Notes                                            |
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Turtle            | 2     | Jump, Jump         |                                                  |
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Sprint stab       | 4     | Sprint + La        |                                                  |
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Sprint dive       | 4     | Sprint + Ha        |                                                  |
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Uppercut          | 8     | La, Ha             |                                                  |
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Spinning uppercut | 8     | La, Ha, La         |                                                  |
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Spinning sword    | 8     | La, Ha, Ha         | This enables you to do the hover combo in air    |
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Headbutt          | 16    | La, La, Ha         | Stuns enemies                                    |
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Headbutt strike   | 32    | La, La, Ha, Ha     |                                                  |
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Drill combo       | 50    | La, La, La, Ha, Ha | You also need 15 point in magic to do this combo |
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

### Unlockable Magic combo's

```
+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Name             | Magic Points | Combo           | Notes                                                    |
+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Magic splash     | 0            | Magic + Ha      |                                                          |
+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Magic projectile | 5            | Magic + Use     | Can also be done in air                                  |
+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Magic slant      | 10           | Air, Magic + Ha |                                                          |
+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Elemental combo  | 15           | La, La, La, Ha  | Does a lot of damage                                     |
+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Magic Jump       | 20           | Magic + Jump    | Useful for the endboss and for setting up an hover combo |
+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I think you'd be fine cutting out the apology for the table, every single question I can find on meta across Stack Exchange is answered by saying ASCII tables is the best option we currently have.

Comment: @QuestionMarks Removed the apology ;) I wish we could use markdown tables.